# Swiftmailer in Messenger __invoke method doesn't send mail

Tags: php, symfony4, swiftmailer

I'm currently having an issue with the use of \Swift_Mailer into a Symfony MessageHandlerInterface. In the __invoke method of this class I would like to send an email with Swift_Mailer.

```
/**
 * @param MailMessage $mailMessage
 */
public function __invoke(MailMessage $mailMessage)
{
    try {
        $message = (new \Swift_Message('You Got Mail!'))
            ->setFrom('no-reply@example.be' , 'No reply')
            ->setTo('development@example.be')
            ->setBody(
                'hello world',
                'text/plain'
            )
        ;

        $successfulRecipientsCount = $this->mailer->send($message, $failedRecipients);
        if ($successfulRecipientsCount < 1 || count($failedRecipients) > 0) {
            throw new \Exception('error sending mail');
        }
    }  catch (\Exception $e) {
        $this->logger->error( $e->getMessage());
    }
}
```

But when I want to consume this messages, the mailer never sends the mail to the destination.
When I use this snippet into a controller it just works. So there is no problem with the mail parameters in my config.

I know that the controller of Symfony dispatch the kernel.terminate event and the Swift_Mailer makes use of this event to sends the emails.

How can I dispatch the kernel.terminate event in the magic method __invoke from the MessengerHandlerInterface from Symfony?